# regex - how to capitalize the first letter of each line inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to capitalize the first letter of each line inside a div
In the example below the result should be:

```
Lorem ipsum
Dolor sit

Amet
```

So each `\n and first letter` should be replaced by `\n and capital letter`

Please help me abut the regex part of my code

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  let str = $('#wrap').text();
  let result = str.replace(/\n a-z/, /\n A-Z/); // how to write this?
  $('#wrap').text(result);
});
```

```css
.wrap{white-space:pre-wrap;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap'>
lorem ipsum
dolor sit

amet
</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\n\s?\p{Ll}`.

1. \n ( new line )
2. \s*? ( optional white spaces )
3. \p{Ll} ( any lowercase letter )

And use the replacement function to match the first letter and replace it with its upper case with `toUpperCase()` function.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  let str = $('#wrap').text();
  let result = str.replace(/\n\s*?\p{Ll}/gu, (v) => v.toUpperCase());
  $('#wrap').text(result);
});
```

```css
.wrap{white-space:pre-wrap;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap'>
čorem ipsum
dolor sit

amet
</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: what if a first letter is a language specific character - for example `č` or `š` in croation language, pls ?

Comment: @provance, I just update the answer, you can use `\p{Ll}` with `u` flag for any lowercase letter. please check again.

Comment: it works. You're a magician. I think regex is the most powerful thing on the planet. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var parts = $(".wrap").text().split("\n");
  $.each(parts, function(i, line) {
    console.log("Line " + i, line);
    parts[i] = line.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + line.substr(1);
  });
  $(".wrap").html(parts.join("\r\n"));
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap'>lorem ipsum
dolor sit

amet</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

This assumes that your HTML or Text has End of Line characters (`\r\n` or just `\n`).

Comment: both solutions works. I accepted the Mina's just because of smaller score. I hope that's ok

Comment: @provance that's your choice. Just happy to help.